# Views Dynamic Fields checkboxes to dropdown select

Tags: theming, navigation, views

I'd like to know if there is a way to modify the exposed check-boxes filter of [Views Dynamic Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dynamic_fields) module and convert it to a multi-select dropdown menu (like an ordinary exposed filter).

Unfortunately [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module which makes that kind of modification possible, does not seem to apply on dynamic fields exposed filters.

Could anyone guide me how to make this kind of change on own?

Answer (score 0):

U can do it through hook_form_alter, just check the form_id, and change the type of form element to that of select, it will create select list from checkboxes.

However for making it working u have to write some jQuery.

```
$("#<form_element_id>").on('click', function(){
$(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
});
```